# Can a regular zenmap scan disrupt my network or servers?

Tags: nmap

I'm trying to increase the security on our servers but I need verification that the **Information Gathering** tool **ZenMap** or **NMap** does not disrupt our network while it's scanning the network.

Are there any settings to be very caucious off which might disrupt a network unintendedly? I doub't a regular port scan will cause any harm however, there might be settings I might be overseeing?

Edit: I did a full scan during early hours and found no issues regarding my question above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's impossible to say because it is easy to create a situation where it would disrupt services on your system, but in most cases, it should not.

In the end, you have to know what `nmap`  actually does with the options you use and how your systems with the configuration you created will react to this. A standard install of an OS should usually remain unaffected from an `nmap` port scan, but in the moment you go beyond that, you have to know what you are doing.

Example: If you have a piece of software that bans IPs doing a port scan  installed on your system and you happen to run `nmap`  from your gateway, you'll effectively cut your server from the outside network.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you already know what ports you have open by looking at your firewall acls?

Anyway, if you are just checking ports - no.

Doing UDP floods might cause minor disruption, but I don't think you're planning on doing anything like that.

At worst, you'll just be flooding your **network** with unnecessary traffic.